# How to lag a vector then create a matrix?

Tags: r, vector, lag

I'm plan to write a function called `lagit(a,k)` to get a result like this:

```
lagit(c(1,5,6,4,7),c(1,3))
```

then it should output:

```
    L0 L1 L3
    1  NA NA
    5  1  NA
    6  5  NA
    4  6  1
    7  4  5
```

I'm facing 2 problems right now:
1. lag each column as each element in vector k;
2. how to bind a vector to a matrix(I used a `for loop`.

I was asked to use the functions in `base` only. So I can't call any functions from other packages.

Comment: `sapply(c(1,3), function(x) lag(c(1,5,6,4,7), x))` does what you want

Comment: @Ben373 I had posted an answer based on `data.table::shift` and you are using `dplyr::lag`. They asked for a `base` solution.

Comment: @nicola thats funny since `lag` is not a `base` function but from `dplyr`

Comment: @Ben373 that's what I said.

Comment: There is is also `diff` funtion from base to do the job

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lagit <- function(a,k) {
   tmp <- lapply(k,function(i) c(rep(NA,i),head(a,length(a)-i)))
   res <- cbind(a,do.call(cbind,tmp))
   colnames(res) <- paste0("L",c(0,k))
   res
}
lagit(a,k)
#[1,] 1 NA NA
#[2,] 5  1 NA
#[3,] 6  5 NA
#[4,] 4  6  1
#[5,] 7  4  5
```

Where:

```
a <- c(1,5,6,4,7)
k <- c(1,3)
```

Comment: Thx! but how to name each column as needed?

Comment: It's pretty trivial. However, I edited the answer to include the naming of the columns.

Comment: Much appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach

```
x <- c(1,5,6,4,7)

# Define a function that operates on a vector x
lagit <- function(x, k) {
    stopifnot(k >= 0 & k <= length(x))
    replace(rep(NA, length(x)), (k + 1):length(x), x[1:(length(x) - k)])
}
```

While not strictly necessary I've added a `stopifnot` statement to ensure that the lag is positive and less or equal to the length of the vector.

```
# Use sapply to apply lagit to different lags and store result as a matrix
sapply(c(0, 1, 3), function(k) lagit(x, k))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1   NA   NA
#[2,]    5    1   NA
#[3,]    6    5   NA
#[4,]    4    6    1
#[5,]    7    4    5
```

Answer (score 0):

A **recursive** solution:

```
myLag <- function(x, n){
  if(n > 0) myLag(c(NA, x)[1:length(x)], n-1) else x
}
```

The ability of this function is equivalent to `dplyr::lag()` and `data.table::shift()`. Let's test it:

```
myLag(1:10, 3)
# [1] NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

In your case:

```
a <- c(1,5,6,4,7)
b <- c(1,3)

> sapply(b, myLag, x = a)

[1,]   NA   NA
[2,]    1   NA
[3,]    5   NA
[4,]    6    1
[5,]    4    5

> cbind(a, sapply(b, myLag, x = a))

[1,] 1 NA NA
[2,] 5  1 NA
[3,] 6  5 NA
[4,] 4  6  1
[5,] 7  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution

```
myLag <- function(x, n){
  if(n >= length(x))
    return(rep(NA,n))
  else if(n < length(x) & n > 0) 
    c(rep(NA,n), x[1:(length(x)-n)]) 
  else 
    x
}

lagit <- function(x,y){
  cbind(x, sapply(y, function(z) myLag(x,z)))
}

> lagit(c(1,5,6,4,7),c(1,3))
     x      
[1,] 1 NA NA
[2,] 5  1 NA
[3,] 6  5 NA
[4,] 4  6  1
[5,] 7  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option that uses `vapply` and `length<-` under the hood

```
lagit <- function(a, k) {
  l <- length(a)
  k <- if (0 %in% k) k else c(0, k)
  vapply(k, function(x) `length<-`(c(rep(NA, times = x), a), l), numeric(l))
}
lagit(1:5, c(1, 3, 6))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]    2    1   NA   NA
#[3,]    3    2   NA   NA
#[4,]    4    3    1   NA
#[5,]    5    4    2   NA
```